# faces FormSignature with JMeter?

Tags: jsf, testing, load, jmeter

I have to load test an application that uses javax.faces.FormSignature in almost every request it sends. I'm using a xPath extractor like this to get the value of the FormSignature:

```
/html/body/div/div/div/form/input[@name='javax.faces.FormSignature']/@value
```

Then I'm declaring a user defined variable and parsing the value I get using a regular expression extractor like this:

```
value=(.+?)
```

I used the HTTP Proxy Server to record my session so I'm 100% sure what GET requests to extract these values from and the POST requests that will use the values as well. It's nto working and I haven't found anything online about using FormSignature and JMeter. I'm pretty new with JMeter too on top of that. Can anybody please help me?

---

Ok, I had the Tidy option checked before. And the xpath works (I've checked in firebug). Here's what I have: there's a jmeter user variable called FORM, then I use the xpath mentioned above to extract a value and apply it to FORM. Then I use a regular expression extractor to extract the value only (value=\"(.+?)\"). I'm applying this regex extractor to my jmeter variable ${FORM} since this is the one (I think) that contains the result of my xpath I extracted before. The reference name of this regex extractor is FORMVALUE and this is the value I'm passing to the post request. I'm not getting a clear error, it's jsut not working. The value that is being passed to my request is the default value I set which is "FORMVALUE not found". Any ideas?

Comment: You can test your regex expression on response data using ViewResultsTree listener. Just select Regexp tester in the drop-down box at the bottom of the left hand panel in your ViewResultsTree listener.

Comment: Yes, the regex seems to be working fine. I'm not sure about the xpath, though. I'm trying to get a clarification of someone that has used this same scenario with the FormSignatures before.

Comment: You say it's not working. What exactly happens, which error? For testing XPath you can use http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using XPath Extractor to parse HTML (not XML) response ensure that **Use Tidy (tolerant parser)** option is CHECKED (in [XPath Extractor's control panel](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)).

Use xpath query from mbonaci's answer below, check the option mentioned above and try again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't quite help. I've updated my question, please take a look and see if it makes more sense.

Comment: Huh. **Then I use a regular expression extractor to extract the value only (value=\"(.+?)\").** Why? What for? Using xpath query like **//input.../@value** will give you value itself, not in form **value=...**. Remove this excessive with regex extractor and use ${FORM} itself - this should contain what you want. [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) may be useful to track values of you jmeter variables.

Comment: Thanks, Alies. The problem with mbonaci's xpath is that it returns more than one possible value and I'm interested in only one of the FormSignatures. So, I'm not sure if jMeter is getting the correct one.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but looks like you should have single javax.faces.FormSignature input item like **<input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.FormSignature" value="HASH_GOES_HERE"/>** on the page. In this case accurate xpath query will return the single value. ...As well [Testing a JSF Application with JMeter](http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/PerformanceTestingWithJMeter) if not yet.

Comment: Yes, I knew that link already. I got this working finally!! Thanks much, Alies!!!

Comment: Nice if so. What is your solution and what was the issue?

Comment: Stupidity was my issue. Didn't have Tidy checked in every xPath extractor since I'm using many different FormSignature values around the tests. Also, the xPath I had before wasn't working in jmeter, only in firepath. mbonaci's type of xPath worked better, just had to add the form id to it like: //form[@id="name of the form"]//input[@name="javax.faces.FormSignature"]/@value since I have many FormSignatures throughout the response code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried without the full path and with double quotes, like this:

```
//input[@name="javax.faces.FormSignature"]/@value
```